# Show different website based on the current State on AWS using Cloudfront/S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We want to show a different website depending on the current State of the visiting user, is it possible? I've seen you can do Restriction, but I guess this is kind of the opposite.

Without a Redirect would be awesome, ie. using different S3 buckets.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What does the `current State of the visiting user` mean?

Comment: @jellycsc yeah sorry, wasn't sure how to formulate that, but I meant which state of the US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamically-route-viewer-requests-to-any-origin-using-lambdaedge/) to inspect the request and redirect the user as you wish.

Here is a  [standard pretty URL redirect](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/#!/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:621073008195:applications~standard-redirects-for-cloudfront) example that you can adjust to your needs.

You can also add multiple origins e.g. S3 buckets and use path matching pattern to direct traffic based on the URL to specific path.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible without the redirect? Like serve from a different S3 bucket if the ip is form X State.

Comment: You can add multiple origins and use path pattern to match URL to specific origin

Comment: Thanks you pointed me in the right direction: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamically-route-viewer-requests-to-any-origin-using-lambdaedge/